# how to convert value from column to row in excel

Tags: excel

Anyone can guide me how to convert from column to row.

Please see my info below:-

```
T3423000A   C71
T3423000A   C54
T3423000A   40A
T3423000A   28A
T3423000A   22A
T3423000A   N85
T3423000A   C73
T3423000A   C97
T3423000A   N40
T3423000A   N43
T3423000A   N60
T3423000A   C72
T3423003F   N91
T3423003F   N88
T3423003F   N74
T3423003F   N65
T3423003F   N40
T3423003F   R19
T3423003F   V14
T3423003F   T48
T3423003F   T40
T3423003F   T29
T3423003F   S67
T3423003F   S38
```

on top is the information that I have duplicate value on the left and I need to merge it. On the right hand I have different value and I need to convert into row which match the value on the left.

Example:-

```
T3423000A C71 C54 40A 28A 22A N85......
```

is there a way I can make in excel without albeit with the following example on top?

Answer (score 1):

With most recent release of Microsoft-365, you can try-

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A24) &" " & BYROW(UNIQUE(A1:A24),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:B24,A1:A24=x)))))
```

Or `HSTACK()`.

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A1:A24), BYROW(UNIQUE(A1:A24),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:B24,A1:A24=x))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sir my excel is microsoft office 2019 and i have try both method. Both of the method is not working